# Eager loading when calling a relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have these tables in  my DB and they are related

```
category
products
product_images
product_categories
```

in Category model I have  (please ignore syntax errors)

```
function ProductCategoryLatest()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCategory')->limit(6);
}
```

in my ProductCategory model I have

```
   function Product(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Product')->where('hidden' , 0 );
   }
```

in Product model I have

```
   function Image(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
   }
```

I want to show last 6  product of each category in my index 
so I read and send categories from controller to my view

```
$categories = Category::all();
return view('index' , compact('category'));
```

in the view, i have something like

```
@foreach($categories as $category)

     {{$category->title }}  products :

     @foreach($category->ProductCategoryLatest as $product_category )

             {{$product_category->Product->title }}

             @foreach($product_category->Product->Image as $image  )
                 <img src="{{$image->title}}">
             @endforeach


     @endforeach

@endforeach
```

as you can imagine there are lots of queries that can be avoided by eager loading but the thing is that limit 6 is ruining it

like if I write my query like

```
$categories = Category::with('ProductCategoryLatest' , 'ProductCategoryLatest.Product' , 'ProductCategoryLatest.Product.Image')->get();
```

and I have 5 categories in my DB the query would be something like

```
select * from product_categories  where category_id  in (1,2,3,4,5) LIMIT 6
```

so if a category with id 1 has like 10 rows in product_categories all the 6 returned rows would belong to category 1  and the rest would come back empty even though they have associated rows in DB but that limit 6 would cuz them to show up without any row in product_categories

so basically I need to eager load in the view on relation something like

```
@foreach($categories as $category)


    @foreach($category->ProductCategoryLatest->with('Product' , 'Product.Image' ) as $product_category )

    @endforeach


@endforeach
```

btw I know I can do some juggling in the controller like

```
$new_categories = [] ;
foreach ($categories as $category )
{
    $ProductCategoryLatest  = ProductCategoryLatest::where('category_id' , $category->id )->with('Product' , 'Product.Image')->get();
    $category->ProductCategoryLatest = $ProductCategoryLatest ;
    $new_categories[] = $category ;
}
```

but I wonder if there is a cleaner solution?

---

so to sum it up my relation

```
class Category extends Model { 
    function ProductCategoryLatest()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductCategory')->limit(6);
    }
}
```

on this code

```
$categories = Category::with('ProductCategoryLatest')->get();
```

would generate this query

```
select * from product_categories  where category_id  in (1,2,3,4,5) LIMIT 6
```

but I want 6 rows for each category_id not 6 for all of them like

```
category_id= 1 -> 6 row 
category_id= 2 -> 6 row
category_id= 3 -> 6 row
```

....

Comment: you can accept and upvote my answer if you got the results > https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can use `take()` and `skip()` for this from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)

```
$categories = Category::with('ProductCategoryLatest' ,
'ProductCategoryLatest.Product' , 'ProductCategoryLatest.Product.Image')
->skip(0)->take(6)->get();
```

Comment: sorry project was on a hold for a while , this wouldn't work  , ive edited my question and added a sum up at the end which i think makes everything clear

Comment: your answer seems to  put 6 limit on `Category` selection not `ProductCategoryLatest` , isn't it ?

Comment: yes. it will put limit on category I guess you need to put limit on that?